# SQL n:m query for return TRUE or FALSE if has data in related table

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if the title got confused. I didn't know how to explain the question properly.
I hope to be more successful now.

I have an n-to-m relationship between Vehicles and Optional

**Table Vehicles:**

```
id, name
```

**Table optional_has_vehicles**

```
optional_id, vehicle_id
```

**Table optinals**

```
id, name
```

I need to build a query to get all optinal data by vehicle, returning true if the vehicle has the optional, or false if it does not.

I have no idea where to start, any help is appreciated.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cross join the `vehicles` and the `optionals`, and check if there is a corresponding record in `optional_has_vehicles` with a `left join`:

```
select 
    v.id vehicle_id,
    v.name vehicle_name,
    o.id optional_id,
    o.name optional_name
    (ov.optional_id is not null) has_optional 
from
    vehicles v
    cross join optionals o
    left join optional_has_vehicles ov
        on  ov.vehicle_id = v.id
        and ov.optional_id = o.id
```

If the given `optional` is available for this vehicle, column `has_optional` produces `1`, else it gives `0`.